# how 20 equates the $\frac {\pi} {9 ln(10)}$.

Tags: calculus

Sorry for a very basic question but I was looking into derivation in a paper . the equation is
$$  \frac d {d \theta }20 log (R sec (\theta )) $$ $$ = \frac {\pi} {9 ln(10)}  tan (\theta ) $$ I dont know how the 20 equates the $\frac {\pi} {9 ln(10)}$. Am I missing something.

Comment: What is $R$ and how are $x$ and $\theta$ related?

Comment: What are $R$ and $\theta$? Without the definitions, $d/dx$ of something independent of $x$ is $0$ ...

Comment: Sorry the derivative was w.r.t to theta and R is a constant which eventaullay cancels out I have checked this derivation log(R sec(theta)) = tan(theta) but I am not sure about the 20

Comment: The appearance of $\pi$ and $\ln10$ indicates that $\theta$ is measured in *degrees*, and the log is actually $\log_{10}$ (why nothing about this in the question text?!).

Comment: Yes sorry because it was not mentioned in the equation